# Express checkout difference between Website payments standards and PayPal payments Pro

Tags: paypal

I have already implemented the PayPal recurring payment section using Express checkout in Website standard Payments. Now I am asked to implement the same recurring payment using Express check out in PayPal Pro. On checking the integration guide, I found that Express checkout steps are same in pro and Website Standards and the only difference i found is Direct Payment is only present in Pro.

Is my conclusion correct? Can I reuse the code i used for recurring in website payments using express checkout ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance 
Boney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  Recurring Payments with Express Checkout will be the same regardless if you have Website Payments Standard or Website Payments Pro.  It would only be different when setting up Recurring Payments for Website Payments Pro.

Comment: What? "Recurring is the same in Standard and Pro. Recurring is only different in Pro." Those two sound opposite?